# Calculating a number based on another number

Tags: php

I'm fairly new at trying to do something like this, I've never really had to work with numbers very much in php.  What I'm certain of is that there has to be a better and more efficient way to do this.

Basically, it checks the input, which is anything between 0 - 28, and then based on that, the modifier is determined.

My head is a little fried right now and this is what I came up with.  It works, but it's pretty horrible.

```
function calc_modifier($input1) {

    if ($input1 < 2) {
        $modifier = 5;
    } else if ($input1 < 4) {
        $modifier = 4;
    } else if ($input1 < 6) {
        $modifier = 3;
    } else if ($input1 < 8) {
        $modifier = 2;
    } else if ($input1 < 10) {
        $modifier = 1;
    } else if ($input1 < 12) {
        $modifier = 0;
    } else if ($input1 < 14) {
        $modifier = 1;
    } else if ($input1 < 16) {
        $modifier = 2;
    } else if ($input1 < 18) {
        $modifier = 3;
    } else if ($input1 < 20) {
        $modifier = 4;
    } else if ($input1 < 22) {
        $modifier = 5;
    } else if ($input1 < 24) {
        $modifier = 6;
    } else if ($input1 < 26) {
        $modifier = 7;
    } else if ($input1 < 28) {
        $modifier = 8;
    }

    return $modifier;
}
```

Comment: You could use a `switch` instead, but bottom line is that you will need to have checks for the range of the input, and it will still look fairly ugly.

Comment: You can maybe make array of keys as your input and values as your modifier and loop throught tho check is key less or what and get value?

Comment: and array with 29keys would be an easy look up scheme

Comment: `function calc_modifier($input1) { return abs(5 - floor($input / 2)); }`

Comment: @zerkms typo extra 1

Comment: @smith ? .............

Comment: @zerkms $input**1** or edit the other varaible to add 1 i dont care :-)

Comment: @smith too late, not editable anymore :-( Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having some experience doing this kind of simplifications it's easy to spot the general formula would be

```
abs(5 - floor($input1 / 2));
```

If you need to restrict/validate `$input` to be strictly in the `[0; 28]` range it should be done separately.

Comment: This will work even though their data is not mapped 1:1 (ie `<2 = 5`)? Edit I guess so, will play with it - interesting approach :)

Comment: That's pretty much perfect, now I know what I need to go read up on.  Thanks!

Comment: @James the behaviour of the function outside of the declared range is not explained in the question (hence is arbitrary). So I added a warning that if it's required - it should be done separately.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your needs (note it's not tested). You might want strict comparison in the loop e.g. `$input1 === $input_to_match` but I don't know your data types.

```
function calc_modifier($input1)
{
    $modifiers = get_modifiers();

    foreach ($modifiers as $input_to_match => $modifier_to_return) {
        if ($input1 == $input_to_match) {
            return $modifier_to_return;
        }
    }

    // return a default value, null or false etc
}

function get_modifiers()
{
    return [
        2 => 5,
        4 => 4,
        6 => 3,
        8 => 2,
        10 => 1,
        12 => 0,
        14 => 1,
        16 => 2,
        18 => 3,
        20 => 4,
        22 => 5,
        24 => 6,
        26 => 7,
        28 => 8,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your cumbersome repetitive code by using data structures to your advantage. In this case, you could try to use an array and use a `foreach` to loop over it:

```
function calc_modifier($input1) {

    $mapper = array(
      2 => 5,
      4 => 4,
      6 => 3,
      8 => 2,
      10 => 1,
      12 => 0,
      14 => 1,
      16 => 2,
      18 => 3,
      20 => 4,
      22 => 5,
      24 => 6,
      26 => 7,
      28 => 8
    );

    $mapperValues = array_values($mapper);

    foreach ($mapperValues as $key => $value) {
      if ($input < $key) {
          $modifier = $value;
        }
    }

    return $modifier;

}
```

Also make sure to have a catch-all that will initialize $modifier if none of the conditions are met.